# Selenium webdriver trying to access popup context

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to authorize Selenium to install an extension but there's no way to get to the popup context:

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 

#The extension
driver.get("https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/ether-metamask/")
time.sleep(1) 

#Perform the act that opens the new window

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Agregar a Firefox')]").click()
```

Popup that shows up:

[image: popup that shows up]

The popup that shows next cannot be inspected by the browser and I tried to access it by `driver.switch_to_alert` but that was worthless.